# Cannot find module '@angular/compiler' in command prompt

Tags: angular, module, find

I installed angular cli on command prmt using this  command npm install -g @angular/cli@latest and after i tried to run my app that  it says" Cannot find module '@angular/compiler' in the terminal". How can i install the compiler in my package.json in order to compile my application

```
{
  "name": "project-new",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~7.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "~7.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~7.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "~7.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~7.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "~7.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~7.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~7.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "~7.0.0",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "rxjs": "~6.3.3",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.10.6",
    "@angular/cli": "^7.0.6",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~7.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "~7.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "~4.5.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~3.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.11.0",
    "typescript": "~3.1.6"
  }
}
```

Comment: delete `node_modules` from current working directory and install again using `npm install`

Comment: I tried out what you told, but still i am facing same issues bro. Please help me to resolve this problem.

Comment: Try delete your `package-lock.json` and run `npm install` again

Answer (score -1):

```
1 : npm install -g @angular/cli
2 : ng new "your project name"
3 : ng serve : error >>> do not worry
4 : npm install @angular/compiler-cli
5 : npm install typescript
6 : npm install @angular/cli
```

it is work !!

Comment: now it is throwing another error that " can not find module @angular/compiler

Comment: repeat the process